# JSON property not updating the value for new key on third function call

Tags: javascript, json

I apologise in advance for the title, I haven't found what I have been looking for while debugging but I may not know the correct terms to search for.

I have the following object:

```
const Game = {

user: {

  tool: {
    displayName: "shovel",
    level: 0,
    max: 1,
  },

  backpack: {
    level: 0,
    max: 10,
    contents: {
      ice: 5,
    }
  }
},

locations: {
  lifePod: {
    displayName: "Life Pod",
    loseOxygen: false
  },
  icyPlain: {
    displayName: "Ice Plain",
    loseOxygen: true,
    materials: {
        type: "ice",
    }
  },
  metalPlain: {
    displayName: "Metal Plain",
    loseOxygen: true,
    materials: {
        type: "metal",
    }
  }
}
};
```

I would like to use the following function to increase the count of the item in ice by 1. This works 100% of the time correctly, however when I try to use "metal" instead, it only allows a maximum of 2.

```
function mineResource(locationName) {
  let newLocation = Game.locations[locationName];
  if (Game.user.currentLocation != "lifePod" && newLocation.materials != undefined && backpackNotFull()) {
    var alreadyInserted = false;
    materialType = newLocation.materials.type; //ice
    materialAmount = Game.user.tool.max; //1

    let {backpack} = Game.user;
    if (backpack.contents != null || backpack.contents != undefined) {
      for (item in backpack.contents) {
        if (item == materialType) {
          Game.user.backpack.contents[materialType] += Game.user.tool.max;
          alreadyInserted = true;
          refreshValues();
        } else if (alreadyInserted) {
            null;
        } else {
            Game.user.backpack.contents[materialType] = materialAmount;
            refreshValues();
        }
      };
    };
  };
}
```

I am confused by the fact that this function works fine with Ice but not Metal. As a test I changed:

```
contents: {
          ice: 5,
        }
```

to:

```
contents: {
          ice: 5,
          metal: 5,
        }
```

And call Game.user.backpack.contents showed only {ice: 5} and calling contents.metal was undefined. I had definitely saved and refreshed. Unfortunately as I am a beginner I don't know what I don't know and it's hard to search for this. I have a put console logs underneath the "if (item == materialType) {" line and they were outputting but not increasing the counter.

If you want to see the whole code it's on http://oxygen.meddleso.me/main.js

EDIT: I did just remove Ice, and made metal the default with 5 and now Metal goes up by 1 normally, but if I add Ice like I was adding metal, Ice only goes up to 2 now.

Comment: Have you tried "var Game" instead of "const Game"? https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/const

Comment: That didn't fix it. Though I did just remove Ice, and made metal the default with 5 and it now goes up normally, but if I add Ice like i was adding metal, Ice only goes up to 2 now.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When you add metal, but have ice, before adding metal you do

```
   } else {
        Game.user.backpack.contents[materialType] = materialAmount; // remove this line
        refreshValues();
    }
```

So when mining metal you do contents['metal'] = 1 (on ice loop) and later contents['metal'] += 1 (on metal loop)... Since you are looping over **item** set contents[**item**]. But I´m sure you would not want to set contents['ice'] = 1 either when mining metalPlain, so just remove this line.

Comment: That is a check to add the material if it doesn't exist though. So if it is looping the backpack.contents looking for ice to check if it exists, and doesn't find it, it adds a new object.

Comment: Then change that line for: if (!Game.user.backpack.contents[item]) Game.user.backpack.contents[item] = 1 and set alreadyInserted to true if you want to give only one free new material per mining, apart from the mined one

Comment: Thanks for that, that seems to have done it. 

  `  } else {
                if (!Game.user.backpack.contents[item]) {
                  Game.user.backpack.contents[item] = 1;
                }`